# Use index to assign drawable value

Tags: java, android

I have a bunch of `ImageViews` in my XML file

Their IDs are:

```
ivIcon0
ivIcon1
ivIcon2
ivIcon3
```

If I have an `int k;` value of 1 I want to only display `ivIcon1` and if I have `int k` value of  0 I want to display 'ivIcon0`

I tried the following:

```
int iconResource = R.id.ivIcon(k);
```

Which gives me an error. I am sure it's simple but can't seem to figure it out. I want to set the `background` of the ID matching the `iconResource` to `R.drawable.iconpressed`

I have a widget which has the following line:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgetlayout);
```

And then I can use the following line to set the image source:

```
views.setImageViewResource("THE ID FROM THE INDEX", "THE DRAWABLE");
```

But the above two lines does not work in an `Activity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an int array:

`int[] resources = { R.id.ivIcon0, R.id.ivIcon1, R.id.ivIcon2, R.id.ivIcon3 };`

And then access the id by using `int iconResource = resources[k];`

OR get the id from a String (if you're doing this in an activity, replace "context" with "this"

```
int iconResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ivIcon" + k, "id", context.getPackageName());
```

And then to get the view you do: `ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(iconResource)`

Personally, I prefer to use the int-array approach as long as the number of possible id's isn't too big. When using the get-id-from-String approach you will end up with the id 0 if it was not found, while the values in the int-array will produce a compiler error if they are not found.

Comment: I updated my question because what you replied correctly but I asked in a wrong context... sorry. Can you let me know how to update it. Thanks.

Comment: The second method work but instead of getting the integer value how so I get the drawable?

Comment: Posted my solution with your assistance! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution that works in case others need it in the future:

```
if(Arrays.asList(myarraylist).contains(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()))) {
        int index = Arrays.asList(suspendedDates).indexOf(df.format(Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US).getTime()));

        int k = MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier("ivIcon" + index, "id", MainActivity.this.getPackageName());

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(k);

        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.caliconpressed);
    }
```